# Wrong 2nd Argument, Found: "com.test.me", required "android.support.v4.app.Fragment" when using replace (with fragment transaction)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
MainActivity fragment1 = new MainActivity();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

My MainActivity extends FragmentActivity. But replace wants the 2nd argument type to be android.support.v4.app.Fragment...
I did a lot of googling on this and none of the solutions helped me. I don't want to change MainActivity so it extends Fragment instead - that would give me more problems but it would fix this one.

Is there any way I could put a cast on 'fragment1' in some way? I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `fragment1` is an `Activity` not a `Fragment`, and as the error says, it expects a `Fragment`. If you really don't want to change for it to extend `Fragment`, then launch it as an activity

```
public void launchMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```